# Can a user have more gold badges than silver or bronze?

Tags: discussion, badges

While learning Python, I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/4284627) where the asker, impressively, has 3 gold, 9 silver and 3 bronze badges.

I'd always assumed each silver badge had a bronze badge that preceded it, and each gold had a silver, so gold >= silver >= bronze. But between this and getting my first Yearling badge, I can see this isn't the case.

Now, trying for more gold badges than silver/bronze may ruin the user experience of Stack Overflow. For instance, I have one gold and one silver from visiting codereview 100 days in a row, when I could have been asking questions or, at the very least, voting.

But all the same, I wondered:

1. Is it possible for a user to have more gold badges than silver badges/bronze badges?
2. Do the people in charge want to make sure this does not happen?

My guess is no. I've had a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) and found nothing obvious, but I was wondering if I missed a special case.

Comment: [6,180 rep from one question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395371/julie-raswick) :D Can it happen? Yes. Is it common? No.

Comment: FYI here's [The only user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710717/preshing) with more gold badges than silver badges (3|2|7). Reason for that is the Populist badge as explained in Nicol's answer.

Comment: I've had this same question for a long time.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt That user has the same number of gold and bronze badges, both lower than silver... and that was the case when you posted the comment.

Comment: My comment was not meant to answer the question. First part of that comment was only a fun fact about the user of the linked question. Second part was only a "I am lazy, but basicly yes it is possible" answer. @jpmc26

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147406/discussion-on-question-by-aschultz-can-a-user-have-more-gold-badges-than-silver).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I can only find users where [gold >= bronze + silver](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/685515) and that all seem to be enthusiast and  Fanatic badge holders.

You could only end-up with more gold badges than bronze+silver if the gold badge is awarded without having a bronze or silver cousin.

I'm not sure if I get this right but I think it should be possible to have more gold badges than any other badges if you, provide only answers

- <s>of +20 score (but less than <25) to a question of -5 score ([reversal badge, now retired](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/))</s>
- +20 score to a question (but less than <25) that was at a -3 score that got to +3 ([lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat))
- that outscores an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x (populist)

But this only works if the question was at a score < 1 to prevent getting the teacher badge.

That should give you one bronze Nice answer badge and 2 gold badges. But if that answer gets beyond 25 the game is over because that earns you another silver good answer badge.

In theory you could have two other badges that don't have a bronze or silver counter part: Constable and Sheriff. But that requires that you are appointed as pro-tem moderator which is unlikely if you don't have any moderation badges (which all have bronze, silver and gold cousins) or get elected as a moderator, where we step of over the fact that for [being elected as a moderator requires having Civic Duty, Strunk&White, Deputy and Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8),  and then step down. I can assure you that getting elected with only more gold badges than any other badges is only happening in your dreams.

Comment: Wow! @Nicol Bolas's answer was also illuminating, but I never knew about data.stackexchange.com, so you get the checkmark. I'll be using the data.se.com for my future odd queries. Thanks!

Comment: You can't earn the Sheriff badge without having at lest 4 silver badges since [being elected as a moderator requires having Civic Duty, Strunk&White, Deputy and Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8). So it's not only unlikely to be elected as a moderator without moderation badges, it's impossible.

Comment: @Donald Just to note that's SO specific. The badges aren't required on other sites.

Comment: *" I can assure you that getting elected with only more gold badges then any other badges is only happening in your dreams."* What if that is your campaign motto? If someone said he wanted to be elected just to see if he could get more gold badges than silver+bronze I would vote for him **instantly**. What this says about democracy is an exercise left to the reader :P

Comment: Bye-bye, Reversal badge...

Answer (score 28):

There are many badges for things that don't have a lower-grade equivalent. For example, the [Reversal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) badge. Oh sure, Reversal's 20-upvote requirement does effectively mean you'll get "Nice Answer". But Reversal doesn't have a *direct* equivalent. Which means that it's possible to get "Great Answer" for the same question you got "Reversal" on, which gives you 2 gold badges, 1 silver, and one bronze.

Indeed, with [Populist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist), it's possible to score 3 gold badges for an answer that only nets 1 silver and 1 bronze.

So yes, it is very possible to get more gold badges than silver and bronze. Unlikely, but possible.

> Do the people in charge want to make sure this does not happen?

I don't see why it matters. The point of having different grades of badges is not just to have lower-ranked versions of the same concept (Great/Good/Nice Answer/Question). It is also to reward certain kinds of behavior specifically or call out certain unusual things that happened. [Guru](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru) for example rewards being upvoted *and* accepted.

Comment: There's a bit of "silver badge inflation" that happens for a lot of answers. The Enlightened/Good Answer/Guru combo that gives out 3 silvers for only 1 bronze. This is probably why a lot of people have almost as many silver badges ad bronze. Gold is much harder though.

Comment: @Mysticial you missed Necromancer from your list (though admittedly I guess it's unlikely to coincide with Enlightened). If, like me, you mostly answer old questions, then effectively there's a 5-score threshold for the silver Necromancer badge followed by a 10-score threshold for the Nice Answer badge, leading to getting significantly more Necromancers than Nice Answers.

Comment: @MarkAmery I still have 5 times more Nice Answers than Necromancer though... (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=badges)

Comment: @VonC well, you clearly aren't primarily answering old questions, then. Whether Nice Answer will outnumber Necromancer for a given user is heavily dependent upon how they find questions to answer; people who find them via the front page will have more Nice Answers, while people like me who usually only answer questions that they've stumbled upon through Google will have more Necromancers, since the majority of questions they answer will meet the age requirement.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, you can theoretically get gold badges without having silver or bronze at all due to how the awarding system works. Basically, for each badge there is a periodical job that checks if any new badges should be awarded.

Lets say you get 20 upvotes on an answer to a -5 question. The Reversal badge check happens to go first and the badge is awarded. Then you suddenly get 11 downvotes. The Nice Answer badge job runs after that, hence you don't get it awarded.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you can get [multiple gold badges from each review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/323179), the answer is clearly yes.

The most extreme case: Anyone can review edits on their own posts. If a 1 rep user were to review (say) 3000 edits this way (not doing anything else on the site or even having an answer on an upvoted question), they would have 3 gold badges but only 1 silver and bronze, all from review. (Though I can’t see this happening in practice as it would just be too suspicious, and it’s very difficult to avoid getting any bronze badges.)

Alternatively, a 500 rep bounty would allow a new user access to the review queues, though you can’t be a good reviewer without doing actions that earn other (usually bronze) badges, such as commenting, and it’s only a matter of time before the user starts earning silver yearling badges.